# How to solve the conflict between tp-link bluetooth dongles?

Tags: usb, keyboard, bluetooth, dongle

So I have tp-link bluetooth dongles. One for my laptop and other one for my desktop.I use logitech k480 bluetooth keyboard.

Here is the image of the keyboard:[Logitech K480 Bluetooth Keyboard](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/keyboards/k480-multi-device-wireless.920-006342.html)

1.There are 3 channels on the keyboard and each channel can be assigned to a new device capable to have Bluetooth connections.

2.My laptop and desktop don't have bluetooth.That's why I am using tp-link usb bluetooth dongles for both laptop and desktop

3.Now If I connect it using the 1st channel with the laptop then I have to connect it with the desktop through the 2nd or 3rd channel.

4.The problem is if I connect to the laptop then connect it with the desktop through another chaneel and then if I want to switch back to the laptop, the keyboard won't recognize the laptop.It shows paired but doesn't work here is the image [paired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vegB3.png)

5.Now I have to remove it and reconnect it with the laptop.If I do that then the keyboard won't recognize the Desktop Bluetooth.Same thing happens for both of them.It's because I'm using the dongles comes from the brand which is tp-link.

6.Now If I use another brand's dongle then this doesn't happen.

So my question is why this is happening and how to overcome it?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is very unclear. Are you trying to make the keyboard recognized by both the desktop and the laptop at the same time? That won't work. Bluetooth connection works basically the same way your Wi-Fi connection works - the keyboard has a bluetooth radio and antenna, as does your dongle, and one antenna can associate with exactly one antenna at a time.

Comment: Sorry New here! Well if you see the keyboard it has 3 channels.I have posted the image link please see.You can assign up to 3 different Bluetooth capable device with the keyboard.All you have to use the dialer to switch to the device.

Comment: No worries, friend :-) I'd still suggest you try to clarify your problem. Write it down as bullet points - how it should work; what exactly happens when you try to switch to different system with the dialer; how exactly do you get around it, do you unplug a btooth dongle, if so, where; what have you already tried to resolve the problem; and so on... [this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) might help you formulate the question a bit clearer. Dang I need to get one of those...

Comment: one more thing - best not to answer questions in comments, but update your question as needed. That way all relevant info is easily available for anyone who wants to pitch in.

Comment: I'll try my best to make you understand.Please tell me if the question needs further details or editing.

Comment: Excellent writeup mate - easy to figure out especially after you added the result of cross-testing with the other dongle :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your testing shows this only happens when you use 2 similar TP-Link dongles. This indicates that your gut feeling is correct - the dongles are the problem.

Since these come from the same manufacturer, the most likely root cause is that they're simply working on the same frequency; i.e. channel. As BT is a short-distance technology, this wouldn't be a problem if they were used in different rooms but when set close together they will interfere with each other. Unfortunately BT dongle manufacturers don't see fit to publish the channel on which their adapters work so this can't be confirmed without a very expensive spectrum analyzer.

There's nothing you can do about this, the channel is hard-coded. The only way around is the one you already found - use another adapter. The only practical way to find a pair that works is to test. Alternatively you could get in contact with Logitech tech support, explain your situation and ask if they can help finding a solution.